# How to use a green texture map from a game character?

Tags: texturing

I extracted a game character and along with it came this green texture map with the filename postfix Exp. is this engine specific or is can it be used somewhere in blender?[image]

Comment: A Halloween mask?

Comment: Complete and total guess: Use a separate RGB node. Plug red into Subsurface and green into Specular

Comment: This practice is called channel packing

Answer (score 4):

Well, I had the same question for the same reason and I finally worked it out. Apparently it's a Unity thing. What you're looking at is an RGBA texture map. G has ambient occlusion, R has metallic, B has something they call a "Detail Mask" but I didn't immediately get the purpose, and A has has the "smoothness" mask which is an inverse of roughness in the form of 1-sqrt(roughness). Here is more than you probably want to know: https://raytracing-docs.nvidia.com/mdl/api/html/mi_neuray_example_distilling_unity.html

Comment: Followup: yes, I suspect you can use them in Blender. You'd just need to pull the image into your favorite image editor and bust the 4 channels into individual grayscale files. The smoothness is probably the only odd item, but I'm sure there's a blender filter which could be used to convert to roughness.

Comment: There is also the Separate RGB node in the node editor to get each cannel without relying on external software.

Comment: But separate rgb only has access to alpha in the compositor

Comment: You can pull alpha straight from the image texture node