# How do I apply "mix" and "op" maps?

Tags: modeling

I'm wondering if anyone's worked with the animal crossing models from the-models-resource? I am still new to blender. I know what to do with the alb and nrm maps but I'm wondering what I am supposed to do with the "mix" and "op" maps? Files are available here: https://we.tl/t-I0JONfJtY5

Comment: Hello Hannah :). Please add those maps into your post. Naming conventions aren't always the same across the board. And please also add a link to the model you're referring to.

Comment: @JachymMichal Hi! I've uploaded the files here: https://we.tl/t-I0JONfJtY5 Please have a look and let me know what u find?

Comment: Related: [How to use a green texture map from a game character?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/190903/78972)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All those textures are prepared for the glTF format, but with some caveats:

1. The *Mix texture* contains Ambient Occlusion, Metalness and Roughness
2. The *Normal map* has inverted B channel (it was probably baked with flipped normals)
3. The "OP" texture is empty, so there's no need to use it at all

Since these models are made by fans in their free time, some issues are to be expected :).

[image]

[image]